# Old prototxt syntax in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, protocol-buffers

I'm working with some older branch of caffe. Now I need to modify the prototxt file by slicing the input layer.

I know that in the new syntax it looks like this:

```
layer {
  name: "slice"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "labelAndMask"
  ## Example of layer with a shape N x 5 x Height x Width
  top: "label"
  top: "mask"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 1
  }
}
```

What would be the equivalent in the old prototxt format? Also, where in the caffe sources could I look this up by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the bottom of [`$CAFFE_ROOT/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L1204), you'll see the `V1LayerParameter` definition.

For old syntax slice layer:

```
layers {
  type: SLICE # this is NOT a string, but an enum
  name: "slice"
  bottom: "labelAndMask"
  ## Example of layer with a shape N x 5 x Height x Width
  top: "label"
  top: "mask"
  slice_param {
    axis: 1
    slice_point: 1
  }
}
```